# Using one sql statement for different search combinations

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I implementing this search method in my Java program that takes search input from 1 to 5 textfields and searches for a object fulfilling the search criteria.

4 of the database columns are in one table but 1 is in another, that I can JOIN in the search.

Thing is this is just an AND search, meaning if i.e. only name has input then search for object having that name, but if name and age has input then object must have both. My conclusion is that these are 31 search combinations and I could  create AND query for each one using If, but can I somehow create one SQL statement that ignores empty input, but includes it if not empty?

Example
Table to search in person

TextField 1 Name :"John"

TextField 2 age:""

TextField 3 weight: 120

TextField 4  hair color: "Green"

The SQL would ignore the select from age since the input was empty, but use AND search for the other 3 conditions.

Comment: It does require "dynamic SQL". In plain JDBC you'll need to concatenate strings; if you are using an ORM a few tags will do it easily for you. Are you using plain JDBC or an ORM?

Comment: I am using plain JDBC

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  You have mentioned two tables, but it is not clear what they are.  You have mentioned an "object", but it is not clear what that refers to.

Comment: Object was wrong word to use here, I am looking for IDs that fulfill the search critera, i.e. in the example I would like to get the unique personId of all rows that have the values in the the columns: name, age and hair color. The second table does not maybe matter in this question. More if I can ignore empty Textfields but include them in SELECT * ...AND  query if they are not empty?

Answer (score 1):

One solution to the general problem of handling parameters is to use `or`.  Something like this:

```
where (name = :name or :name is null) and
      (age = :age or :age is null) and
      . . .
```

You would adjust the `from` clause to always `join` the tables -- perhaps with the `left join` (your question is not clear).  Or, you might use an `exists` subquery.

Note:  The above construct requires scanning all the rows in the table.  It cannot make use of indexes.  However, indexing a table for a fast search on 2^n combinations is itself quite tricky.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/). There's no point in creating code for problems that have already been solved, because you will need to write, test, and maintain that code.

QueryDSL allows you to build queries dynamically, using Java classes. So you would add a clause for each of your input boxes. If you ever need to add or remove a text box, do the same in your code.